# How can I upgrade Freya 0.3 to 0.3.1?

Tags: updates

It doesn't show on update manager (as someone told it could be done thay way); Also, I updated kernel to .19 version but updater has new updates for .16 version... I have ppa installed, should I keep them? On updater settings, should all options be "ticked as ok"?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [announcement in the official blog](http://blog.elementary.io/post/128271333121/freya-031-is-here):

> If you’re already running Freya, you will already have received all of
>   the above (with the exception of the newly added hardware support) in
>   your regular updates.

So, by normally updating your system you get the 0.3.1 release (bar the hardware enablement stack). If you want the full experience, a clean install is always recommended.

Comment: I have problems getting updates. Sometimes it doesn't install everything, just partially. The OS already shows on info 0.3.1 version. But now I can't install stuff correctly and always getting the warning **boot partition low space** (actually 0 bytes left). Like I stated in a comment below

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a re-install, using the 0.3.1 iso. You can do so without losing your data. See link

https://askubuntu.com/questions/269880/re-install-ubuntu-without-losing-data-in-home-folder

I would also do an Aptik Backup too. I've updated 3 systems to 0.3.1 using this with no data loss.

Comment: I can't do complete updates but somehow, the last time I tried the OS info shows version 0.3.1 but that caused some problems: since this happened I always get notification/warning (when booting and installing apps - which sometimes fails) which says **boot partition no space left** or something similar. I searched on the topic but I don't know which files to remove from boot partition/folder and I don't know how to merge boot and root partitions. If I do as you say, would this get solved?
(obrigado pela resposta)